# What would be the way to learn algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, self-learning

I want to know the mathematical theory associated algorithms. Story with a base of calculation, analytical geometry and linear algebra. What would be the previous topics to begin the study of algorithms?

Comment: The three (or is it seven?) volume series [The art of computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) by Donald Knuth should keep you busy for a while.

Comment: yeah...for a while...

Comment: @WimC  Clearly, suggested books contain topics on which I want to learn. My question is directed more to know if I need some more knowledge base, in addition to what I have already. Anyway, many thanks.